# #superfish ul also targets contextual links!

Tags: theming, navigation

I am using [superfish menu](https://drupal.org/project/superfish) in D7 as follows:

- I have created a custom theme from scratch
- in my page.tpl.php I have created a region for my main menu as:

  ```
   <div id="superfish"><?php print render($page['main_menu']);?> </div>
  ```
- I place the superfish block inside the main_menu region and it appears in place, as expected.
- I write my .css, but **when I target #superfish ul, the contextual links are also targeted and styled**! I suppose this is not the normal behaviour.

In all other modules I've encountered (including nice menus), contextual links are kind of greyed out and cannot be targeted with CSS, but in the context of Superfish menu they appear active and targetable as ever. They even get superfish classes applied to them.

What am I missing?

P.S. I am starting using `#suckerfish ul:not(.contextual-links)` :-O

Comment: Would the answer be different if problematic CSS would appear in Joomla, or any other CMS with superfish menu plugin? Looks like universal CSS thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try targetting `#superfish ul.menu`. This should discriminate the menu from `ul.contextual-links`. (Double check the class for your menu by viewing the page source if this does not work.)

Comment: Ohh, how dumb am I :O thank you very much, I started using `#suckerfish .content ul` to bypass the contextual links. Such a simple solution, doh! Do you happen to know if this is the normal behaviour of superfish? (sth get's screwed up because contextual links also rely on js?!)